# Docker Daemon API upgrade to v1.4

Tags: docker

I'm unable to use the below command to use Nvidia GPUs inside the container:

```
docker run --gpus all nvidia/cuda:10.0-base nvidia-smi
```

**"--gpus" requires API version 1.40, but the Docker daemon API version is 1.39**

It requires API version 1.4 :

````
docker version                                        
Client: Docker Engine - Community
 Version:           19.03.12
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.13.10
 Git commit:        48a66213fe
 Built:             Mon Jun 22 15:45:36 2020
 OS/Arch:           linux/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          18.09.9
  API version:      1.39 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.11.13
  Git commit:       039a7df
  Built:            Wed Sep  4 16:19:38 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false ```
````

I'm unable to find a way to upgrade the daemon API.

Please help.

Comment: You need to upgrade the system's Docker daemon.  I would typically expect the two versions returned by `docker version` to be the same; what setup do you have that they're different?  (Are you using Docker Toolbox, or did you manually set the `$DOCKER_HOST` environment variable?)

Comment: @david maze : I followed the basic instructions for installation of docker. Yes I have manually set it . Should I remove everything and re-install ?

Comment: You shouldn't need to set `$DOCKER_HOST` at all.  What did you set it to?  Why did you set it?  What's your host OS?

Answer (score 3):

I had the exact issue. For me updating `docker-ce` worked.

```
$ apt search docker-ce                                                                                                    
 Sorting... Done
 Full Text Search... Done
 docker-ce/xenial 5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-xenial amd64 [upgradable from: 5:18.09.6~3-0~ubuntu-xenial] Docker: the open-source application container engine

 docker-ce-cli/xenial,now 5:19.03.12~3-0~ubuntu-xenial amd64 [installed,automatic] Docker CLI: the open-source application container engine

$ apt install docker-ce
$ docker run --rm --gpus all nvidia/cuda:11.0-base nvidia-smi
```

As you can see, I had docker client `docker-ce-cli` (v19.03) installed but the docker server installed was `v18.09`.

Answer (score 0):

If there's no possibility to update the `docker` (if you're have no root rights on this very machine). And assuming `nvidia-docker` installed, try the following signature:

```
nvidia-docker run --rm \
  ...
  -e NVIDIA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0,1 \
  ...
```

That way you'll call `nvidia-docker` runtime and restrict visible GPUs with 0,1 (you choose which ones to have visible)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo apt upgrade docker-ce
```